# Paypal verify arbitrary payment

Tags: php, rest, curl, paypal

Can I verify any arbitrary PayPal payment-ID from my server?

As stated here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/ in *Looking up a payment using the REST API* section, I should send a request looking like this:

> curl
>   https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI
>   \
>   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
>   -H "Authorization: Bearer
>   {accessToken}"

What if i pass instead of PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI any other *correct* payment-id, which does not belong to me (I am neither a payer, nor a receiver)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal will not surrender information about payments to callers who are not a party to the payment (and who don't have permission to act on behalf of one of those parties).

Comment: Seems you are right.

Tried with real (sandbox) payment id and got the following response:

`{ 
 "name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
 "message":"The requested resource ID was not found",
 "information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
 "debug_id":"e7195654ff304"
}`